# When adding layerId to addPolygons(), the polygon does not show up

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a polygon which I can add perfectly fine to the leaflet using addPolygons, but I am trying to give it a layerId, so I can remove it later on. I cannot use clearShape() as I have more than 1 layer. So I want to use removeShape(layerId). But when I add the layerId to the addPolygon it does not show the polygons anymore. The relevant part of my script is:

```
 colorData <- region2@data[, "contP"]
 colorData[colorData == 0] <- NA
 pal <- colorNumeric(c("lightblue1", "steelblue3", "blue", "green","green3","green4",
                    "yellow","gold","darkorange","red","red2","red4","magenta","purple1"), c(0,30),
                  na.color = "transparent")
 leafletProxy("map") %>%
 # removeImage("colorRaster") %>%
 #  removeShape("colorLegend") %>%
  addPolygons(data=region2, weight = 1, color = "black", fillColor = pal(colorData), fillOpacity = 0.5, layerId="colorLegend2") %>%
 addLegend("bottomleft", pal=pal, values=c(0,30), title="Mean P", layerId="colorLegend")
```

Any hint on why this happen?

Comment: I know this is old but I also had this problem so I'll write something here. when using `addPolygons()` the `layerID` argument needs to be a vector of unique layerIDs for each shape added. Otherwise leaflet draws over the each feature in turn. I found the answer [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) under "Understanding Layer IDs"